# Weird Phrase Search

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow, search

On Stack Overflow, the phrase:

> "Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer" reference

returns nine search results. But

> "Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference"

returns no search results (it shows the Search Options page), and

> "Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an" outer reference

returns 5,000+ search results.

What's going on?

Comment: It looks like the second query is too long, but can't be truncated because of the quotes, the first query gets truncated before the unquoted term (reference) and performs an exact match search on the quoted text, and the third query gets truncated so that there's a quoted string + unquoted term (outer), which results in it searching for posts with all the individual terms anywhere in the post. Definitely weird...

Answer (score 4):

This is fixed as part of [the new search engine changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160100/a-new-search-engine-for-stack-exchange).  Here's your query now: ["Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Each%20GROUP%20BY%20expression%20must%20contain%20at%20least%20one%20column%20that%20is%20not%20an%20outer%20reference%22)

Comment: so .... `status-completed`?